# How to convert pcap to avi file with video and audio by gstreamer?

Tags: audio, video, gstreamer, pcap, avi

I need to read a pcap file and convert it into a avi file with audio and video by using gstreamer.

If i try the following command, it only works for generating a video file.

## Video Only

**gst-launch-0.10 -m -v filesrc location=h264Audio.pcap ! pcapparse src-port=44602 \
!"application/x-rtp, payload=96" ! rtph264depay ! "video/x-h264, width=352, height=288, framerate=(fraction)30/1" \
! ffdec_h264 ! videorate ! ffmpegcolorspace \
! avimux ! filesink location=testh264.avi**

## Audio Only

And if i use the following command, it only works for generating a audio file.

**gst-launch-0.10 -m -v filesrc location=h264Audio.pcap  ! pcapparse src-port=7892 \
! "application/x-rtp, payload=8" ! rtppcmadepay ! alawdec ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! avimux ! filesink location=test1audio.avi**

## Video + Audio

When i combine two commands as follows, i encountered an error message -- 
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc1: Internal data flow error.

**gst-launch-0.10 -m -v filesrc location=h264Audio.pcap ! pcapparse src-port=44602 \
!"application/x-rtp, payload=96" ! rtph264depay ! "video/x-h264, width=352, height=288, framerate=(fraction)30/1" \
! ffdec_h264 ! videorate ! ffmpegcolorspace  \
! queue ! mux. \
filesrc location=h264Audio.pcap pcapparse src-port=7892 \
! "application/x-rtp, payload=8" ! rtppcmadepay ! alawdec ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! queue ! avimux name=mux ! filesink location=testVideoAudio.avi**

Please kindly give me some solutions or suggestions with regard to this issue. 
Thank you in advance.
Eric

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the 2nd "filesrc ! pcapparse" give the first pcapparse a name=demux, drop the src-port arg and start the 2nd branch from demux.